# Difference between Shapley values and SHAP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, shapley-value

[The Paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions.pdf) regarding die SHAP value gives a formula for the Shapley Values in (4) and for SHAP values apparently (?) in (8)

Still I dont really understand the difference between Shapley and SHAP values. As far as i understand for Shapley I need to retrain my Model on each possible subset of parameters and for SHAP i am just using the basic model trained on all parameters. Is that it? So SHAP is computationally easier?

Comment: shapley values represent the contribution of features/players in certain prediction/reward. Shap has incorporated this concept to find the features importance in machine learning context.

Comment: The same question is answered here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203472/difference-between-shapley-values-and-shap-for-interpretable-machine-learning